# How to use JSoup to grab a specific value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsoup

I'm trying to parse html text to grab a specific value after a keyword. For Example on the code below:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td class="odd">TW-Central</td>
        <td class="odd">$3.8600</td>
        <td class="odd">$3.8600</td>
        <td class="odd">$3.8600</td>
        <td class="odd red">-0.0168</td>
        <td class="odd right">42,500</td>
        <td class="odd right">7</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td class="even">Waha</td>
        <td class="even">$3.9600</td>
        <td class="even">$3.8800</td>
        <td class="even">$3.9196</td>
        <td class="even red">-0.0436</td>
        <td class="even right">69,500</td>
        <td class="even right">17</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td class="odd">White River Hub</td>
        <td class="odd">$3.8200</td>
        <td class="odd">$3.7975</td>
        <td class="odd">$3.8088</td>
        <td class="odd red">-0.0184</td>
        <td class="odd right">81,200</td>
        <td class="odd right">13</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

After the keyword Waha is found, how would I be able to grab the price under it and return it?
Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm also coding this in Java using STS, if JSoup is not the best to achieve this, advice on what to use would also be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is not going to change it's position just get all the td elements and then select with the get(index) method the one you want.

```
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    html.append("  <table>");
    html.append("    <tr>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"even\">Waha</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"even\">$3.9600</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"even\">$3.8800</td>");
    html.append("    </tr>");
    html.append("  </table>");

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html.toString());
    Elements tdElements = document.select("td");
    String waha = tdElements.get(0).text();
    String firstPrice = tdElements.get(1).text();
    String secondPrice = tdElements.get(2).text();

    System.out.println("The first td content is: " + waha);
    System.out.println("The second td content (firstPrice) is: " + firstPrice);
    System.out.println("The third td content (secondPrice) is: " + secondPrice);
```

Update:

To dynamically select use the following code:

```
@Test
public void testJSOUP() {
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    html.append("  <table>");
    html.append("    <tr>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"odd\">TW-Central</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"odd\">$3.9600</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"odd\">$3.8800</td>");
    html.append("    </tr>");
    html.append("    <tr>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"even\">Waha Row</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"even\">$4.9600</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"even\">$5.8800</td>");
    html.append("    </tr>");
    html.append("    <tr>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"odd\">White River Hub</</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"odd\">$4.9600</td>");
    html.append("     <td class=\"odd\">$5.8800</td>");
    html.append("    </tr>");
    html.append("  </table>");

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html.toString());
    Elements trElements = document.select("tr");
    for (Element tableRows : trElements) {
        Elements tdElements = tableRows.select("td");
        String articleName = tdElements.get(0).text();
        String firstPrice = tdElements.get(1).text();
        String secondPrice = tdElements.get(2).text();

        System.out.println("The article: " + articleName + "has price one:" + firstPrice + " and price two:" + secondPrice);
    }
}
```

This will create the following output

> The article: TW-Centralhas price one: $3.9600 and price two: $3.8800
>    The article: Waha Rowhas price one: $4.9600 and price two: $5.8800
>    The article: White River Hubhas price one: $4.9600 and price two: $5.8800

Comment: The important thing is that the html code needs to valid. In your example it is missing the table tag

Comment: sandrozbiden Ok awesome this makes sense, thank you! Question, if the Table format is not going to change, and the name "Waha" is not going to change, only the value under it. Will this code still work?

For example if the price is going to be updated every day, how can I grab the new and unknown value?

Comment: If the table is not going to change then you can get the first price always with the command tdElements.get(1).text(). But for sure you need to always parse the complete html Jsoup.parse(html.toString()) and then select for td when you want to see the changes. When your html is a little bit bigger (has other tables in it) then we need to find a better filter.

Comment: Just need a little more clarification and ill make it as closed, thanks I appreciate your time. So you're saying once I use the command assertEquals("Waha", tdElements.get(0).text()); I have to do what command to always grab the unknown price under it??

Comment: Okay I realize you are new to java. assertEquals is a method used in UnitTesting. I will simplify the example and then you can see what there is to do

Comment: You are welcome. If you want you can accept the anweser by clicking on the pick on the right side of my answer. Thanks

Comment: Makes much more sense, thank you! My last and final question. The line Elements tdElements = document.select("td"); is grabbing all the td in the table correct? (the real one has multiple tr and td) Could I use this to grab al the tr?

Comment: Then from there find the specific Waha I need, then grab the price I need under it. Following this example?

Comment: I updated the code so you can better understand what I asking

Comment: The variable tdElements has all tdElements that you parsed. If the tables has multiple tr elements then you need to select the td element that you want to getThe method document.select("td") will return all td elements from all tables, and tablerows (tr). Then with tdElements.get() <-- you add the position which td you want

Comment: Awesome, you explain very well. Thank you again. I understand now. SO if "Waha" happens to be the 18 td then ill will do the following to return it String waha = tdElements.get(17).text(); Thank you for your time and patience good sir.